# Loop in R: Store output in a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, pca

Here is the problem I am currently facing:
I have a data frame (let's call A) of 96 observations (rows) and 16 variables (columns).
I also have a rotation of 9 column vectors (from a Principal Components Analysis) of 16 elements (coefficients for each of the 16 variables of A).

The PCA rotations are saved as such:

```
ph=prcomp(home[ ,3:17], scale. = TRUE)
Home_vec=-round(ph$rotation[ ,1:9], 3)
```

Now, singularly I have been able to multiply one of the rows of my data frame by the object Home_vec and the output is equal to multiplying the row by each of the 9 PC columns, and applying cbind.

For example, the row input:

```
TEAM=c(5, 1503, 26.31, 16.2, 0.099, 33, 28, 368, 35, 15, 84, 942, 528, 33, 315)
```

My new output:

```
TEAM.1=round(TEAM*Home_vec,3)
```

I have created a for-loop which carries out this procedure for each of the 96 observations in my data frame.

```
F=function(x){
  x*Home_vec
} 

for(i in 1:96){
    print(F(home[i,2:17]))
}
```

The only problem is - I'm struggling to save the output (which is a 96 by 9 data frame) as a new object.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following with your loop:

I am using the package dplyr.

```
x <- "" %>% data.frame

for(i in 1:96){
y <- F(home[i,2:17]))
x <- bind_rows(x,y)
}

x <- x %>% .[-1,-1]
```

Comment: Christiaan thank you very much, this worked for me.
However, it worked when I substituted the equation for x at the top for the one at the bottom. If you don't mind me asking, what exactly does the x <- x %>% . [-1,-1] do?

Comment: EDIT: I realized that the top line WAS necessary, apologies. I needed to reorder the code though: the bottom line was put second. I am still curious as to what these two lines are instructing the computer to do.

Comment: At the top I created an empty dataframe, (1x1 dataframe), then in the loop you bind the new rows to the empty dataframe. The last line just removes the first row and first column of the empty dataframe created. (Run the loop without the last line and then view x before running last line to see what happens)

Comment: ps, please vote me up if the solution helped, I can do with some experience ;).